# ArcGIS Survey123 collecting data from multiple map questions

Tags: arcgis-survey123, arcgis-survey123-connect

I am new to Survey123 and created a survey using the web app. For the purposes of my survey, I wanted to collect multiple location based data points from each respondent. I didn't realize that on Survey123 I could only have one map question.

I have already received several replies. Even though the respondents filled out multiple map questions, I can only see the GIS data from one of the questions. I was wondering if there was a way I could access the data from the other map questions, and if not if there was a way to have multiple map questions on the web app.

Comment: In order to generate multiple geometries in a survey, you need to use repeats.  I don't think repeats are available in the web app.  So you may need to use Survey123 Connect instead of the web app if you want to do this.

Comment: Alternatively, there is a hack to do it without repeats (and storing the data in coordinate columns, instead of as actual geometries).  See the second option in the accepted answer at:  https://community.esri.com/t5/arcgis-survey123-questions/multiple-geopoints-in-survey123/td-p/826769 .  But I think this too would not be possible using the web app, as it requires use of calculated hidden answers.